# ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font React-native, Android

Tags: react-native

This happened after I've added custom fonts on iOS to assets, added

`"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }`

to my package.json and ran react-native link.

After that I couldn't build android.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we I ran react-native link it created copies of some libraries in 3 files:
**android/app/build.gradle**:

I had `implementation project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')` and it added `compile project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')`

**android/app/src/main/java/com/pivot3/MainApplication.ja**:

it added second import

`import ca.jaysoo.extradimensions.ExtraDimensionsPackage;`

and second package to asList

`new ExtraDimensionsPackage(),`

**android/settings.gradle**:

it added extra
`include ':react-native-extra-dimensions-android'
project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-extra-dimensions-android/android')`

Probably my react-native link script is broken (I didn't change) but in case you have the same error, check these 3 files for duplicate copies.

Removing extra copies fixes the issue.